# Await async worklow started in thread pool

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Is it possible to start an async workflow in the thread pool, and, **at some later point**, await its completion, similar to starting a `Task` and later calling `Result`? I know it's possible start an async workflow and await it at the same time. The key is deciding to await its completion later on.

Comment: you mean like storing the `Task` in a variable and `await` it's completion later?

Comment: Correct. But with an `Async`.

Comment: I don't get it. `async` is a implementation detail. From the outside it is "just" a function that returns a `Task`. And `await` works on every instance of `Task`. No matter if the function returning the `Task` is `async` or not.

Comment: This question is about F# `async` workflows, not .NET `Task`s.

Comment: Isn't that the same concept? You can store the `Async` with `let` and fetch it's value later with `let!`.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like using `Async.Start`, then later using `Async.RunSynchronously` to await completion? I didn't know that was possible, but might be worth trying.

Comment: I am thinking something like using `Async.StartImmediate` to get the `Async` object and using the `let` to store the `Async` object and using `let!` to later retrieve the value computed in the `Async` object (and await it's termination). I am rarely using F# so I can't be of more help.

Comment: The calling code isn't in an async workflow, so I would have to use something like `RunSynchronously`, if this approach works.

Comment: @Nitram: Actually, this doesn't work because it runs the workflow a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Async.StartChild` - you can run this inside an asynchronous workflow and it schedules another asynchronous operation to be started in the background (by default, this will add it to the thread pool). The operation gives you another `Async<'R>` back that you can use to await the completion of the background operation.

```
let backgroundOp = async {
  printfn "Background operation starting"
  do! Async.Sleep 1000
  printfn "Background operation done"
  return 1 + 1
}

let mainOp = async {
  printfn "Main operation starting"
  let! awaiter = backgroundOp |> Async.StartChild
  printfn "Doing more stuff in main"
  let! res = awaiter
  printfn "Main completed with child result: %d" res 
}
```

**EDIT**: I see from the comments that your calling code is not inside an async workflow. If you can change it so that it runs inside async, that would be probably a better design, but it seems that you can still use `Async.StartChild` and write something like this:

```
// Start the backgroundOp and (synchronously) return awaiter that
// we can use to wait for the result of the background operation
let awaiter = 
  async { let! awaiter = backgroundOp |> Async.StartChild
          return awaiter } |> Async.RunSynchronously

// Now you can use the awaiter to wait for the completion synchronously
awaiter |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: I'm struggling to adapt this to my design (and maybe my design needs a rethink). This is in an API to be used from C#. The C# code will call `Agent.Start` which kicks off an async workflow and returns an `IDisposable` that, when disposed, cancels the workflow and awaits its exit.

Comment: If you're building an API for use from C#, then I'd definitely just go with `Async.StartAsTask`!

Comment: Given that this is a potentially infinitely running task, cancellation is the only way to stop it, so I was hoping to make that invisible.